# How can you call a c++ constructor somewhere other than where you define a variable without calling new?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have a class set up like this:

```
class Foo {
  Foo();    

  private:
     Bar m_bar;
}
```

That is the class definition in  it's own header file, and now in the source file to go with it I have the constructor and I tried doing this:

```
Foo::Foo() {
  m_bar("parameters for the Bar constructor");
}
```

However this doesn't work and gives me an error. I can make m_bar a pointer and then in Foo's constructor do this:

```
m_bar = new Bar("parameters here");
```

However that makes m_bar a pointer and I don't want that.

I'm not the best with C++ classes and pointers, so could something either explain a way for me to have m_bar defined in the Foo class but constructor somewhere else or if it is better to make m_bar a pointer in this situation explain why? While I would rather not make it a pointer(because I don't understand pointers extremely well), if that is the best way to do it then I would rather do it that way, but I'd still like someone to explain why that is the best way to do it(if it is).

Comment: The people saying "initialization list" have it right.  To answer the more general question: You can only provide parameters when calling `new`, when defining a variable, or in class/struct initialization (the initialization list).  So you can't explicitly call a constructor somewhere other than where you define a variable.

Comment: Note that you can cause a constructor to be called without creating a *named* variable...such as instead of writing `Bar myFunction() { Bar result ("parameters here"); return result; }` you can write `Bar myFunction() { return Bar ("parameters here"); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the initializer list syntax:

```
Foo::Foo() : 
  m_bar("parameters for the Bar constructor")
{
}
```

Comment: It seems like with initializer lists, the variable gets constructed before the constructor runs. Is there anyway to have it get constructed after the constructor is finished? Inside of the constructor I load some images and I need to pass those images to m_bar's constructor if they loaded fine. Constructing m_bar before the images are loaded doesn't work(as it then doesn't have any images to use).

Comment: @krej: If you absolutely need to do it in constructors you will need to define a parent class with a constructor that loads the images, then derive from the parent so the child's constructor handles m_bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use initialization lists:

```
Foo::Foo() :
m_bar("and you ought to check out a good C++ book :)")
{
    // Book list: http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you can use the constructor [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) to do so.